# Почему axios post запрос возвращает ошибку 400?

Tags: javascript, post, async-await, axios

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:1337/api';
const token = localStorage.getItem('kobza-jwt');

export async function postArticle(){

    const config = {
        headers: {Authorization:`Bearer ${token}`}
    };
    const bodyParameters = {
        body:{
            title:"test1",
            body:"test2",
        }
    };

    await axios.post(`${URL}/articles`, 
        bodyParameters,config)
    .then(console.log("well done"))
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('An error occurred:', error.response);
    });
}
```

Помогите найти ошибку. Ссылка рабочая, get запрос проходит без ошибок. Сзади у меня Strapi.

Comment: 400 HTTP ошибка появляется если сервер не понимает тело запроса `bodyParameters`  случайно не должен быть просто `{tilte, body}` без обёртки в `body`? А то получается что ты отправляешь `{body: {title, body}}` на сервер. Посмотри что отправляется из браузера в POST (Кнопка F12, закладка сеть), и сравни с тем как надо.

Comment: еще нужно проверить, а что ждет бэкенд? Возможно он ожидает multipart form data, а вы ему json шлете